# Updating Windows Forms application to run on Windows 8.1

Tags: winforms, windows-store-apps

I've some time lately trying to find a clear answer for updating some of my desktop applications to run on Windows 8.1 (Desktop/laptop and Surface). So far everything I am finding is pointing toward developing for the Windows Store where the application then could be downloaded.

Heres my development Environment:

- Windows 7 Ultimate
- MS Visual Studio 2012 Premium
- MS Visual Studio 2013 Express

My test environment consist of:

- Windows 8.1 Surface Tablet
- Windows 8.1 Laptop

When I build something now (retargeted to the newer framework (4.5 (4.5.1 is installed)) and copy it over to these devices and try to run them I get an error that the indicates "This app can't run on your PC" "To find apps for this PC, open the Windows Store.".  This isn't really what I want to do, I just want to make he applications we use on a day to day basis in my retail store availible to the new computers.

A couple of questions come to mind;

- Does the development environment need to be a Windows 8.1 based environment?
- Do I need to again buy a new version of Visual Studio (Visual Studio 2013)?
- Am I stuck using the Windows Store to deploy applications?

If anyone could point me in the right direction as to where to read or provide some insight tho cross this hurdle would surely save alot of repeated reading about how great the store is.

Answer (score 1):

A Surface tablet does not permit running desktop apps.  You can only run apps that are downloaded from the Store.  So scratch the idea that your Winforms app is going to work on the tablet.  There isn't any good reason why it would not work on the laptop, they work fine on mine.

> Does the development environment need to be a Windows 8.1 based environment?

Yes, for VS2013.  For VS2012 it needs to be at least 8.0

> Do I need to again buy a new version of Visual Studio (Visual Studio 2013)?

You didn't buy VS2013, you do need the correct version of Express.  There are several.  You need the "Express 2013 for Windows" edition, it only supports developing apps for the Store.  You probably have the "Express 2013 for Windows Desktop" edition, it only supports desktop apps and supports Winforms.  The retail edition supports all targets.  The Express editions were split to keep them small.

> Am I stuck using the Windows Store to deploy applications?

If you develop Store apps, yes.  You get a temporary license to develop the app but it expires after a month.  If you need more time then you get just another license.  But the app needs to be certified to obtain a permanent license so it can run permanently on the Surface machine.  And everybody else's.

Comment: Little more info: your WinForms desktop apps can still run on Windows 8 and 8.1 as they do right now. They will NOT be able to run on Windows RT, which is probably what you have since you didn't mention Surface RT. The Windows Store and what @Hans told is for the 'Metro' looking apps. If you want your old desktop apps to look like a new Metro app, you need to start all over. You might be able to reuse something, but you need to start learning some XAML or HTML. Good luck!

Comment: Right, covered by the first paragraph.

Comment: Thanks Hans and Sebagomez, that pretty much answered the unanswered for me.  I'll load the VS 2013 Express on the new laptop and rebuild it, if that works then I am at least to where I am currently and will tackle the Tablet as I can.  I was hoping to not have to buy a new version of VS as I just got 2012 about 6 months ago, but it looks to be the way forward from here for Windows 8 an dthe Surface tablet.